# How to click on one button and if form is save to click on other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons and 1 form.
1st button is new button. Button that i want to add. When i click on this new button i want jQuery to click on next button:
2nd button: Save - when this button is clicked need to add function like:

```
if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )   {
```

if this is valid - form is saved successfully jQuery need to click on third button (when this is invalid stop to here. Other js will show errors in form):
3rd button: Send order - after clicked on it do not need nothing. Other js will do the rest.

Other way will be to use "save" button and if is valid to click on "send button" - may be is more is solution?

```
    <p class="orderbutton">
        <input type="submit" class="order-button-opc" id="order-button" value="Order Button">
     </p>
    <p class="submit">
     <input type="submit" class="exclusive button" name="submitAccount" id="submitAccount" value="{l s='Save'}" />
    </p>
    <p class="cart_navigation" id="cart_navigation">
    <input type="submit" value="I confirm my order" class="extraorderbutton">
    </p>
```

I try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var firstFormValid = false;
var isFormValid = false;
$('#order-button').click(function(){
    if(anycondition)
       firstFormValid = true;
});

$("#submitGuestAccount").click(function () {
     if(firstFormValid ) {
     if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 &&$("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )  {
         isFormValid = true;     
     } else isFormValid = false;
     } else firstFormValid =false; 
}); 

$("#order-button").click(function () {
   if(isValid && firstFormValid)
       $('#order-button').submit()
});
 });
  </script>
```

But i get error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope will help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var firstFormValid = false;
    var isFormValid = false;
    $('#newbutton').click(function(){
        if(anycondition)
           firstFormValid = true;
    });

    $("#savebutton").click(function () {
         if(firstFormValid ) {
         if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 &&$("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )  {
             isFormValid = true;     
         } else isFormValid = false;
         } else firstFormValid =false; 
    }); 

    $("#sendbutton").click(function () {
       if(isValid && firstFormValid)
           $('#FORMID').submit()
    });
});
```

Comment: This code for sure will not run because it's missing some brackets

Comment: I look your code but i not i want to do.
I want to add new button and when i click on new button to have function "click save button" if form is valid, then click on third button "send"
I want user to see only one button (other will be hidden with css) and when click on it to do several click. New button->save button-> if form is saved-> click on send button.

Comment: Let me modify it more.

Comment: Nice but i get error on row 5. See edited post. May be will be more easy to use save button and if form is valid to click on other?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just debug/throw some code at you, you could approach this better by working on each of the areas separately, *likely help for this and the future ?*

1. Declare elements/selectors
2. Validate Function
3. Form 'check' function
4. Form 'save' function
5. Event Handlers.

Say,

**1) Declare elements/selectors**

```
var _inputemail = $("#email"),
_inputfirstname =$("#customer_firstname"),
_inputlastname = $("#customer_lastname"),
_button_check = $("#checkbutton"),
_button_send = $("#sendbutton"); /* hidden initially in css */
```

**2) Create a Validate function**

```
function isValid() {
  var is=false;
   /* add in the checks */
  if(_inputemail.val().length>0) { is=true; }
  /* return true or false */
  return is;
}
```

**3) form 'check' function**

```
function checkForm() {
  /* use the validate function */
  if(isValid()) {
   /* show the 'save' button */
   _button_send.show();
  }
}
```

**4) form 'send' function**

```
function sendForm() {
  /* sendform here */
  if(isValid()) {
   /* we could run the validate again if we like  */
  }
}
```

**5) Event Handlers**

```
_button_check.on("click", checkForm);
_button_send.on("click", sendForm);

/* now we  have separate functions we can check/send 
  the form from other events too 

 eg. Checking as we type */
_inputlastname.on("keyup",checkForm);
```

---

Got some reusable / easy to manage 'components' now

*will be some things to sort in this code, but hope helps in someway!* ( ? )

Comment: Thank you @Rob Sedgwick for answer. Very interesting things. I will try to understand this 5 thing and then will try to code something for my case.

Comment: @user3388282, good stuff. Yeah I find that breaking things up helps in the future when we need to do more things - like say print validation messages, we can just go into the `isValid` function to make enhancements knowing all other parts remain intact. A must if working in teams too.